# WatsonのIPアドレスが変更されたら通知されるようにできますか？

Tags: watson-api

DNSで管理する機能がないのでIPアドレスでしか対応できません。SAPやSalesforceではの利用環境でもIPアドレス管理で対応していて、変更の際は連絡が来るのですが、Watsonの場合、IPアドレス変更通知をIBMから受け取ることはできませんか。

お客様環境でWATSON Applicationを稼働させるためには、
169.XYZ.00.XYZ
のようなAddressを取得するにはどうしたらよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

類似の質問がIBMのサイトにあり、公開されているエンドポイントのURLが回答されています。
あるいは該当URLのホストgateway.watsonplatform.netにpingを投げるとか。

[Static IP address when we call Watson API](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/361019/static-ip-address-when-we-call-watson-api/?lnk=hm)

> I guess you are looking for the IP address for the service. Web DNS
>   will resolve the endpoint, which for example for the language
>   translator service is
>   https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api.
>
> So if you ping gateway.watsonplatform.net you will see that ip address
>   the web is resolving the endpoint to.

別に自分自身でDNSを運用している必要は無いのでは？

IBMの開発者向けリソースの [資料](https://console.bluemix.net/developer/watson/documentation) ページからたどれば各機能のAPIリファレンスにエンドポイントのリスト等も記載されています。例えば [Natural Language Classifier](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-classifier) とか [Text to Speech](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech) とか。

同様にサポートしている各言語でのSDKや使い方の案内も記載されているので、それらを参考にされれば良いと思われます。